# how can i use ontouch function to move an image with cursor in android?

Tags: android, touch

*I am making an small application in android in which i used an image and i used two buttons here when i click the first button the image will zoom and when i click second button the image will zoom out. But now i want when the image will zoom i can able to move the image with mouse cursor in emulator or(by touch in devise) so that i can able to view the whole image after zooming.can you suggest me any idea .***

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try just moving the initial drawing coordinates. For instance when the image is first shown, I would imagine that it is at 0,0. when you want to move the image just directly modify the start coords accordingly.